# How can i express in regexp "match until a pattern without including that pattern"?

Tags: regex

I have this input :

```
{http://sdfgdf.dfg.dfg.dfg#value1 : http://sdfgdf.dfg.dfg.dfg#value2}
```

and i'd like to match only the value1 from the first URL.
I thought the below regexp :

```
[^#]\w*\s:
```

but this matches "value1 :"

How can i express "match until \s: ,without including that pattern?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Zero-width lookahead. In [Java](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) you could do it like this:

```
[^#]\w*(?=\s:)
```

You may think about making this regex more flexible, to handle extra whitespaces and such... just in case the input is just slightly different from what you expect.

Comment: That matches only the whitespace after values1.It doesn't work.But i can't understand why.For me it is:Match and word character ->* times,starting after a non '#' char, until you see \s(whitespace) and after the ':'

Comment: @Iraklis I don't know how you tested, but it does work. I've posted that without testing, now I just tested and it works. This second version is slightly safer: `(?<=#)\w+(?=\s*:)`

Comment: Yep,you are right ,it was my fault.Thanks in any case.Very useful for me the lookahead.So it is something like:"heyy regex machine do not match just assert."

Comment: @Iraklis This is because these are 'positive lookaheads'. Likewise, 'negative lookaheads' sound like "this must not be right after/before the match". The name 'lookahead' itself is adequate, it's a quick peek around the match, without returning the match of the lookahead regex.

Answer (score 1):

In all honesty, if your input is always this simple, I wouldn't use a Regex. For example, you can do a string split on " " and take the first item.

```
myInput.Split(" ")[0]; // Example in C#
```

or you can do a substring...

```
myInput.Substring(0, myInput.IndexOf(" "));
```

but if you're really intent on the regex thing...

```
(?=.*\s)[^\s]+
```

That regex reads: "While ahead somewhere is a space, match any character that is not a space."

Comment: I wanted to use only regexp to become more familiar with regilar exxpressions.The above regexp matches the entire "http://sdfgdf.dfg.dfg.dfg#value1" string.I want only "value1" to be matched with the pattern.